# How to download, display blob images in Chrome?

Tags: image, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, blob

I'm trying to open/download an PNG blob image of a website. I used network to find the image but it only display it as plain text.

[image: Network Console Preview]

I'm confused why the small preview image in the list shows the image. How can I download the image or get any kind of working preview?

Comment: Sounds like a devtools bug. Not sure how this is related to development of chrome extensions. If you want to intercept a blob created by the site you'll probably have to use a [page script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) and some deep hooking into the methods used by the site because blob URLs are usually revoked immediately after being loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok first open the webpage where the blob image is and Click inspect, then go to **Network**
after that refresh the page while **Inspect > Network** is open

**Then locate the blob image in Network and click the Preview tab to see if you got the right blob**

[image]

Then **Rightclick on the Preview image** and download the blob image

[image]

[image]

**Then Locate the downloaded blob file**

[image]

**Now rename it with the proper Extension for the image (.png, .jpg, etc...)**

[image: file in folder]
[image]

**Now rename it and click on yes if it asks you for confirmation**
[image]

[image]

And that's it you have successfully downloaded the blob image

Comment: As far as I can see, that's what the thread owner did. Or am I missing something?

Comment: They didn't refresh the page after opening Inspect > Network hence the image they wanted wasn't loaded I think, I also pointed out that they can rename the downloaded blob file to the images Extention (.jpg, .png, etc...) and they can get a working Image file